# Are ISPs able to track individual devices connected to a personal router?

Tags: isp

Quick question about how ISPs and personal routers. So, I have a personal router and have about 13 devices currently connected to the router. Is there anyway that my ISP would know how many devices are currently connected to the line via my personal router? Basically, if I used my personal router, what kind of information does the ISP have access to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What information can my ISP see from my router?](http://superuser.com/questions/840412/what-information-can-my-isp-see-from-my-router), also see [Can my landlord access my personal network because he controls the upstream connection?](http://superuser.com/questions/851048/can-my-landlord-access-my-personal-network-because-he-controls-the-upstream-conn?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing an ISP will see is your router and router MAC address.. However, they can track your usage and history.

If the router was supplied by your ISP, they may be able to go past the router and into your LAN.